# Browser extensions detect install

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, xul

I have one extension in Firefox and one in Chrome. I want to call a javascript function when installing or uninstalling the extension. It is possible in any of those browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Firefox

- Detecting installation is already covered in this answer: [Firefox extension opening a page on install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958893/firefox-extension-opening-a-page-on-install)
- [Sample code to listen for uninstallation of the add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/Code_Samples#Listening_for_add-on_uninstall) (using the [`AddonManager`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager) API)

### Google Chrome

In Chrome, there are no built-in methods to detect installation or uninstallation.

- One can check whether a `localStorage` flag on the [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) exists, and act on that.

  ```
  if (!localStorage.getItem('my-extension-first-time')) {
      // Do something
      alert('Hello first timer!');
      // Set flag
      localStorage.setItem('my-extension-first-time', true);
  }
  ```
- There's no way to listen for the uninstallation of itself.
- The [`chrome.management`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html) API can be used to [monitor](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html#global-events) external extension (un)installations.